# Login and get file with php from asp

Tags: php, xml, asp-classic, automation

I have to login on a asp website and click some links finaly i click on a button that downloads a file (xml file)

can i automate this process ?

I read you can use something like this:

```
$file = "http://domain.com/directory/filename";
$save_path = 'download/';
$fp = fopen($save_path.basename($file), 'w');
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

but the problem is there is a login and there are no direct urls (asp)

Answer (score 0):

Add the login (Authentication basic heder):

```
$username ='useri';
$password = 'pass';
$auth_token = base64_encode($username . '-' . $password);

$headers = array('Authorization=Basic ' . $auth_token,
 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.3) Gecko/20070309   Firefox/2.0.0.3');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ':' . $password);
```

Here you have a full example:

[Example HOW TO use Basic Authorization with PHP cURL](http://jevsbl.blogspot.com.es/2010/03/example-how-to-use-basic-authorization.html)